# Convert PHP result to PDF using PHP? - HTML2FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

So I've been working a bit with *HTML2FPDF*, and I have converting *HTML* to *PDF* working all fine. However, I cannot get any PHP to work. Not even static PHP like

```
echo "hello world";
```

it is just completely ignored. I thought this would render as HTML and it then would be included in the PDF, but it doesn't.

I wanna be able to run some PHP functions and then for the result to come out as HTML like it normally would. Is there a way to do this?

I am thinking that one way of doing this is to load the PHP function first. Then when the function has run and the result shows as HTML, then convert the page. I have tried this for a few hours now, with all sorts of solutions, but I can just not get it to work in any way.

Is there a way to convert PHP results to PDF as well?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have it [installed](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/install.md) properly.

You have just to launch the following command on the root folder of your project:

```
composer require spipu/html2pdf
```